# Is there a good clone of the OS X Finder for Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, file-management, finder

I'm mostly a Windows user, but am a big fan of the "in columns" mode of the OS X finder (the [Miller Columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_Columns) concept). It's fluid, and it's great being able to see the contents of each folder up the heirarchy, and not just the contents of the folder I'm in.

Is there a good clone out there of the OS X finder, or even just the "columns" mode, but for Windows?

Comment: Screenshot of Finder in column view is at the bottom of the linked web page.

Comment: The column UI where the columns are homogeneous is more specifically known as [Miller Columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_Columns) — perhaps that term might help you find a program that does specifically that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Edited question for now. Will do some searching.

Comment: I've seen many more people want this the other way round!

Answer (score 1):

UltraExplorer has a column view mode, but it hasn't been updated for a while.

http://ultraexplorer.mustangpeak.net/